# Failed when `nix-build hello.nix`

Tags: nix

I followed the steps on http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2014/08/nix-pill-8-generic-builders.html to build GNU Hello, and here is the files I used to build GNU hello 2.9:

```
$ wget -c http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.9.tar.gz
```

hello.nix:

```
$ cat hello.nix
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix pkgs;
in mkDerivation {
  name = "hello";
  src = ./hello-2.9.tar.gz;
}
```

autotools.nix:

```
$ cat autotools.nix
pkgs: attrs:
  with pkgs;
  let defaultAttrs = {
    builder = "${bash}/bin/bash";
    args = [ ./builder.sh ];
    baseInputs = [ gnutar gzip gnumake gcc binutils coreutils gawk gnused gnugrep ];
    buildInputs = [];
    system = builtins.currentSystem;
  };
  in
  derivation (defaultAttrs // attrs)
```

builder.sh:

```
$ cat builder.sh
set -e
unset PATH
for p in $buildInputs; do
  export PATH=$p/bin${PATH:+:}$PATH
done

tar -xf $src

for d in *; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    cd "$d"
    break
  fi
done

./configure --prefix=$out
make
make install
```

Error messages:

```
$ nix-build hello.nix
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/d84l57agx3rmw00lxs8gjlw8srmx1bh9-hello.drv
building '/nix/store/d84l57agx3rmw00lxs8gjlw8srmx1bh9-hello.drv'...
/nix/store/vv3xqdggviqqbvym25jf2pwv575y9j1r-builder.sh: line 7: tar: No such file or directory
builder for '/nix/store/d84l57agx3rmw00lxs8gjlw8srmx1bh9-hello.drv' failed with exit code 127
error: build of '/nix/store/d84l57agx3rmw00lxs8gjlw8srmx1bh9-hello.drv' failed
```

It seems there is `gnutar` in the `autotools.nix` but builder still complains `tar: No such file or directory`, why is this?

Comment: Although you have `gnutar` as a dependency, I don't think the builder will get a Nix user environment; In short, `tar` won't be in `$PATH`. So you'll need to use the absolute path to the executable like so in `builder.sh`: `${gnutar}/bin/tar`

Comment: Thx for asking this question I just skimmed over the pill nr. 8 because I got the concept of the generic build and I didn't think it was necessary to do the excercise.
Then for pill 9 i was actively working again so i went back to lesson 8 and just copy pasted the builder.sh , being totally unaware that this isn't a finished code snippet. But that there is a line below that as David Grayson mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `gnutar` is in the `baseInputs` list, while the `buildInputs` list you are building your PATH from is totally empty so nothing will be on your PATH.  Try changing the `for` line in your shell script so that it uses the concatentation of both lists to build the path:

```
for p in $baseInputs $buildInputs; do
```

You can add `echo $PATH` to your builder script to debug issues like this.

That is what the blog post author was asking you to do in this sentence from the post:

> Complete the new builder.sh by adding $baseInputs in the for loop together with $buildInputs.

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nix-pills/blob/353336cc5ad6d68486867fc945ac21d1cda20907/pills/12-inputs-design-pattern.xml#L70
The author said: I remind you, in <filename>autotools.nix</filename> there's a <literal>buildInputs</literal> variable which gets concatenated to <literal>baseInputs</literal>.  That would be the perfect place to add a build dependency. We created that variable exactly for this reason to be overridable from package expressions.  
--- So should I change the `buildInputs` to `baseInputs` in `builder.sh`?